# Golang search specific item inside Struct array

Tags: go

I'm trying to find the best way for searching inside an Stuct array for getting a specific item with the id of the element.

```
type Device struct {
    Addr        net.Addr
    AssignedId  int
    Data        string
}

type RegistredDevices struct {
    AllDevices      []Device
}
```

Right now i do that

```
var currentDevice models.Device
for _, device := range registredDevices.AllDevices {
    if device.AssignedId == id{
        currentDevice = device
        }
}
```

I expected to do something better like that for searching, but i don't know what do to if item can't be find. What should be the return ? Can i return nil or i need to return an empty Device ?

```
func (registerDevice *RegistredDevices) GetById(id int) Device{
for _, device := range registerDevice.AllDevices {
    if device.AssignedId == id{
        return device
    }
    else{
       return ?????
    }
}
}
var currentDevice = registredDevices.GetById(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what this question is asking. Indeed, writing a `for ... range` loop is the idiomatic way to find a value in a slice. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, i want to be able to search using an external function like GetById and retrive my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To signal that an item wasn't found you could either return a pointer to an item (which would be `nil` if not found), or use two return values with an error or a boolean.

For example map lookups return a `value, ok` pair. Example from [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec):

An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment or initialization of the special form

```
v, ok = a[x]
v, ok := a[x]
var v, ok = a[x]
```

yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.

---

In your case it would be:

```
func (registerDevice *RegistredDevices) GetById(id int) (Device, bool) {
    for _, device := range registerDevice.AllDevices {
        if device.AssignedId == id {
            return device, true
        }
    }
    return Device{}, false
}
```

And then:

```
if currentDevice, ok := registredDevices.GetById(1); ok {
    // found. use currentDevice
} else {
    // not found
}
```